# Powershell - StreamWriter only write first line

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv, streamwriter

I´m working on a code that is supposed to import-csv - change the content, and then export to csv.

I´ve tried to export with Export-Csv - but it only writes the lenght of the string
I also tried with StreamWriter - but it only writes $Resultat once

I am new to PowerShell :-)

```
$workfile = import-csv "X:\powershell\converter\test.csv" -Delimiter ';'

ForEach ($item in $workfile)
{
$Id = $item.("ID")
$Maaler = $item.("Maaler")
$Fra = $item.("Fra")
$Til = $item.("Til") 

#Dato gymnastik
$Tilto = $item.("Til")
$Tilto = $Tilto.substring(0,10)


$Til = $Til.substring($Til.length - 8, 8)
$Forbrug = $item.("Forbrug")
$Enhed = $item.("Enhed")
$aflaesningstype = $item.("Aflæsningstype?")
$T = ".000+02:00"

$Resultat = $Tilto + "T" + $Til + $T + ',"' + $Maaler + '","' + '","' + '","' + '","' + '","' + $Forbrug + '","' + $Enhed + '","' + '255"'

Write-output "$Resultat"
}
$Resultat | Export-Csv "X:\powershell\behandlet\Output $(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss).csv" -Delimiter ',' -NoType

#$fhStream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "X:\powershell\behandlet\Output $(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss).csv" 
#$fhStream.WriteLine($Resultat)
#$fhStream.Close()
```

The Write-output shows the output in the right way

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$workfile = import-csv "X:\powershell\converter\test.csv" -Delimiter ';'
$result = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
ForEach ($item in $workfile)
{
$Id = $item.("ID")
$Maaler = $item.("Maaler")
$Fra = $item.("Fra")
$Til = $item.("Til") 

#Dato gymnastik
$Tilto = $item.("Til")
$Tilto = $Tilto.substring(0,10)


$Til = $Til.substring($Til.length - 8, 8)
$Forbrug = $item.("Forbrug")
$Enhed = $item.("Enhed")
$aflaesningstype = $item.("Aflæsningstype?")
$T = ".000+02:00"

$result += $Tilto + "T" + $Til + $T + ',"' + $Maaler + '","' + '","' + '","' + '","' + '","' + $Forbrug + '","' + $Enhed + '","' + '255"'
}
$result | Out-File "X:\powershell\behandlet\Output $(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss).csv"
```

Comment: Thank you for you quick reply. The $Resultat += is removing line-break and slowing the code.

Comment: Almost there I think. Now the csv contains the expected 17000 rows, but with the Length in the cells

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear on this part. Instead of the output of the code, I get the length of the $result string e.g. 83,82,82,83 etc.

Comment: You are my hero :-) Works like a charm - Thanks